# No power when using the Xbox 360 Play N' charge kit

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I have a 360 wireless 360 controller and a play n' charge kit, but I'm not getting any power from it.  I plug it into the Xbox/3rd party USB wall chargers/laptop, and nothing.

And when I say no power, I mean no power to even turn the controller on.  It started where it would only work when there was no battery in the controller, and now not at all.  Has this happened to anyone before?  Did it just give out?

For more information, I have multiple controllers and multiple battery packs, but only one charging cable, so I assume it is the cable itself?

Answer (score 1):

Check the cable thoroughly, I had a knick in mine that caused the entire cable to become worthless. Any extra spiraling in the cable can create a chokepoint that, over time, can overheat the cable and burn through the hot wire making it additionally as useless. Just some things that have happened to me in which case I just purchased a cable on the cheap courtesy of our friends at [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000B6MLS2)

Answer (score 1):

How long have you had it? The play and charge kits are notorious for the batteries dying. If you have another controller try it on that as well, also try using AA batteries to make sure it isn't the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue. Apparently its just that the wireless controller needs a receiver. Using the wire to connect only charges it (affecting only the battery and not powering it). I suggest getting a wireless receiver.